# How to find the shortest path in a graph, that has to go through a list of points and go back to the start?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am working on a coding problem, in which you are given an undirected, unweighted graph, a starting point and a list of points which you have to visit. The graph has n nodes and n-1 edges. How can I find the shortest distance of the path that starts at node 1, goes through all the points in the list, and finishes at node 1. Going through the same node/edge several times is allowed.

INPUT:
First row: integer n denoting how many nodes total (numbered 1-n), then integer k denoting how many must-visit nodes there are.
Second row: k integers denoting the must-visit nodes
Next lines: pairs of integers denoting there is an edge between them

OUTPUT: length of shortest path as described

EXAMPLE:
In:
5 2
4 5
1 2
2 3
2 4
1 5

Out:
6

I was thinking of finding the shortest path between node 1 and all must-visit nodes (for eg. using Djikstra), but I am not sure where to go from there.
Python code would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that online somewhere? Are there limits for the numbers?

Comment: If a Hamiltonian cycle exists for the graph, the optimal solution would be it, so the optimal solution would seem to reveal whether or not the graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle, a challenging problem in its own right.

Comment: Yes, both the total number of nodes and number of must-visit nodes can be up to 100000

Answer (score 2):

To find a path that visits all required nodes, A, B, .. N

```
Loop V over required nodes
     Find path from V to V+1 using Dijkstra
     Add path to solution
     IF V = N-1
        STOP
```

To find shortest path

```
Loop S over all order permutations of required nodes
     Run above algorithm
     If length of path found shorter than best previous
          replace best previous
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, but won't this be way too slow, if the constraint in the problem is that the number of must-visited nodes can be maximum 100 000? Do you have any ideas for how to make it faster?

Comment: The easiest way to make it faster is to drop python and use a compiled language.  C++ will be about 50 times faster.

Comment: Suggestion: post a link to the input for your 100,000 node problem and I'll measure the performance.

Comment: https://po.kattis.com/problems/ekorren in Swedish but you can maybe google translate the site

Comment: Yes, I can try writing it in C++, but I still think it would be too slow. But I'll try

Comment: The examples in the link seem to be trivially small.  Do you have a link to your 10,000 node problem.

Comment: There is no need to write your code from scratch.  There are many implementations of Dijkstra on the net.  You just need to wrap them in the algorithm in my answer.  You could even use my implementation at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2

Comment: " it would be too slow."  What is your required speed for the 10,000 node problem?

Comment: For a better running time you should run an all-pairs shortest path algorithm first and use its results while checking the permutations. You have the problem of finding the minimum-weight closed spanning walk (Hamiltonian walk), which **I guess** is a hard problem. So I don't think you will be able to go much faster than O(n!)

Comment: I don't think you can see the larger examples in the problem, but it has to run in under 3 seconds, so for this input faster than O(n^2). I just realised that it says that there are n-1 edges, meaning the graph is a tree, this should make the question easier.

Comment: Is the graph guaranteed to be connected? If not, it may be a disconnected graph that is not a tree or forest.